# sumGenerator(int termination, int increment)

Tags: java

Have to create a simple for loop, a sumgenerator. The results should look like this.

```
System.out.println(sumGenerator(100, 10)); // 450
System.out.println(sumGenerator(50, 4)); // 312
System.out.println(sumGenerator(1, 2)); // 0
```

So far all i've written down is:

```
private static int sumGenerator(int termination, int increment) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<termination;i+=increment++);
    return i;
}
```

But obviously this is not yielding any results... I get the point here, i think, the increment keeps adding it to itself while also every loop adding himself to the int variable i, and once the i is bigger than the termination the loop stops.

Comment: What's the actual formula here, not just the input and results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// giving people homework answers isn't good for anyone :\

Just add an extra sum variable and remove extra ++ from the loop.

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(sumGenerator(100, 10)); // 450
  }
  private static int sumGenerator(int termination, int increment) {
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<termination; i += increment){
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Live - [jdoodle.com/a/lyA](http://jdoodle.com/a/lyA)

Answer (score 0):

i is just a counter, think about what the code is doing after each iteration of the loop, print it out and understand it. You should create a separate variable to hold the sum. Think about the comparison, we want the calculation to continue to add increments. If we are adding to the thing we are comparing with, we are ending when the sum is above the termination, not when the increment has reached that point.